# Tricky situation with unique ID's and dynamically added items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that when clicked adds a new media item to a list. Issue I have is that it uses unique id's that get duplicated. I need a way to make it add some kind of anonymous number on the id so it doesn't duplicate. Or can I use a class and some kind of .each.closest method to bind it to the right button?

#replaceFeUpload and #replaceFileSelectUpload are the ID's that get duplicated when the media item is added.

HTML

```
<div class="add-carousel-item">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="file" class="fileElem pull-right" id="replaceFeUpload" multiple onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
        <button class="fileSelect pull-right" id="replaceFileSelectUpload">Select Media Item</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="fileSelect">submit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger left-space remove-item">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$("p.add-carousel-item").on("click", function () {

            $.get("/includes/add-carousel-item", function(response) {
                    $( ".carousel-item-zone" ).append(response);
            });

            function click(el) {
                    // Simulate click on the element.
                    var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
                    evt.initEvent('click', true, true);
                    el.dispatchEvent(evt);

            }

            document.querySelector('#replaceFileSelectUpload').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    var fileInput = document.querySelector('#replacefeUpload');
                    //click(fileInput); // Simulate the click with a custom event.
                    fileInput.click(); // Or, use the native click() of the file input.
                    function readURL(input) {

                            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                                    var reader = new FileReader();

                                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                                            $('#img-preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                                    }

                                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                            }
                    }

                    $("#replacefeUpload").change(function () {
                            readURL(this);
                    });
            }, false);
    });
```

Comment: Use classes or `data-something` attributes to store the value. You can't use duplicate IDs on dynamic content. Your click generation seems to be overkill for jQuery... why not just call `click()`? You should really be using delegated events e.g. `.on('click', jqueryselector, function(){ handler here });` and `on('change', `

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: As a comment is not enough to cover all the issues, I have tried to explain in more detail below. If you need more detail, just ask :)

Answer (score 0):

From comment: Use classes or data-something attributes to store the value. You can't use duplicate IDs on dynamic content.

Use code that finds the related element in a relative way:

```
var fileInput = $(this).closest('.add-carousel-item').find('.replacefeUpload');
```

This looks back up the ancestors for the nearest carousel item, then finds the matching upload element.

As an example of using *delegated event handlers* using class filters instead:

**Html:**

```
<div class="add-carousel-item">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="file" class="fileElem pull-right replaceFeUpload" multiple onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
        <button class="fileSelect pull-right replaceFileSelectUpload">Select Media Item</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="fileSelect">submit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger left-space remove-item">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.replaceFileSelectUpload', function (e) {

   var fileInput = $(this).closest('.add-carousel-item').find('.replacefeUpload');

   //click(fileInput); // Simulate the click with a custom event.
   fileInput.click(); // Or, use the native click() of the file input.
   function readURL(input) {

          if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                 reader.onload = function (e) {
                     $('#img-preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                 }

                  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
          }
}

$(document).on('change, ".replacefeUpload", function () {
      readURL(this);                    
});
```

Delegated event handlers work by listening at a convenient non-changing ancestor (`document` is the default if you do not have one handy), *then* applies a jQuery selector, *then* applies the function *to any matched elements that caused the event*. Note: never use `'body'` as the ancestor for delegated events are it has bugs related to styling that mean some events may never occur.

Comment: I am getting some error in console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: I typed this straight into SO, so it is only intended as a guide (not typo-free) :)

Comment: Also getting error, Uncaught ReferenceError: $this is not defined. Tried using just parts of your code, but can't seem to get any of it working.

Comment: that was just a typo for $(this). You must have done that one yourself (I often do) :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep a global JavaScript variable named `offset` (or whatever you want to name it)

Increment offset when adding a field, decrement when removing a field

Then, add this to the id declarations when creating a new field - they will be named:

```
offset = 1;
"fieldName" + offset++ //fieldName1
"fieldName" + offset++ //fieldName2
"fieldName" + offset++ //fieldName3
```

Comment: Looking at the example, the items with ids are dynamically loaded and *already contain the ids*. Changing to classes would be a better idea

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - Definitely not applicable to the provided example code, but if there is a class that generates new fields, it should have that dynamic naming built-in

Comment: You do not need unique classes/names for the example shown. Relative searching will be sufficient to find the one control it needs.